# Performance of WSL1 / Ubuntu 18.04 vs WSL2 / Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04

I have been testing my **WSL1** environment running Ubuntu **18.04** with a new **WSL2** environment running Ubuntu **20.04** on a laptop with a 2 core i5 and 16GB RAM running Windows 10, version 2004, build 19041.388. The filesystem used is a standard Windows NTFS on an SSD drive.

The **older environment performs much better**. I wondered if others had noticed the same?
Would the OS change alone account for the difference?

WSL2 was billed as having higher performance and I saw a quote of "up to 20x faster compared to WSL 1 when unpacking a zipped tarball". That's not been my experience, as can be seen below.

I recognise that I am not comparing like with like as the OS has changed but I am still surprised.
I expect a lot of people moving from WSL1 to WSL2 will also upgrade from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS.

Running the following code

```
#!/bin/bash +x
#1
  time ls -altr > /dev/null
#2
  time head -c 50M < /dev/urandom > /dev/null
#3
  time head -c 50M < /dev/urandom > genran4u.sh.$WSL_DISTRO_NAME
#4
  time for i in {a..e};do
     echo delthis.$i
     tr -dc 'a-z\n' < /dev/urandom  \
     | head -c50M > delthis.$i
  done

rm delthis.tgz
#5
  time tar -zcvf  delthis.tgz  delthis.{a..e}

rm delthis.{a..e}
#6
  time tar -zxvf delthis.tgz
```

on the 2 environments running

```
$ time ./bench_wsl_a.sh 2>&1  | grep real
```

gives

```
Output comparison:

WSL1 + 18.04           |  WSL2 + 20.04
                       |  
#1: real    0m0.285s   |  real    0m3.356s
#2: real    0m0.106s   |  real    0m0.199s
#3: real    0m0.214s   |  real    0m2.375s
#4: real    0m10.829s  |  real    0m23.823s
#5: real    0m13.055s  |  real    0m14.721s
#6: real    0m3.676s   |  real    0m6.651s

Totals
real        0m28.275s  |  real    0m51.229s
```

The 'Legacy' version is consistently faster.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions#exceptions-for-using-wsl-1-rather-than-wsl-2 may explain why. I don't know what "project files" it is referring to though.